# Creating a subset, while removing NA's

Tags: r, ggplot2, subset, geom-bar

I want to create a bar plot with a subset of a certain category and remove the NA's at the same time in R.

This script is working :

```
ggplot(data = subset(data, !is.na(test)), 
       aes(factor(geb_nat), y = ..prop.., group = 1)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  geom_text(stat = "count", 
            aes(label = scales::percent(..prop..), y = ..prop.. + 0.02))
```

and this is working as well:

```
ggplot(data = subset(data, geb_nat != "nat"), 
       aes(factor(test), y = ..prop.., group = 1)) +
  geom_bar() +
  geom_text(stat = "count", 
            aes(label = scales::percent(..prop..), y = ..prop.. + 0.02))
```

But when I want to remove the NA's and the rows with "nat" it removes only one of these.

I tried:

```
ggplot(data = subset(data, geb_nat != "nat", !is.na(test)),
       aes(factor(test),y = ..prop.., group = 1)) +
  geom_bar() +
  geom_text(stat = "count", 
            aes(label = scales::percent(..prop..), y = ..prop.. + 0.02))
```

but I only get the subset with the "nat" and the NA's are still there.

Comment: Use `subset(data, geb_nat!="nat" & !is.na(test))`. `subset` only takes one logical argument (as opposed to `dplyr::filter`).

Comment: Thank you, I was missing that "&". Works really well!